# How can I make Wireshark filter by port when reading from standard in?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I'm piping from a RawCap-generated dump file to Wireshark in order to monitor local traffic, how can I instruct wireshark to only show traffic to a certain destination port?

I'm running RawCap in one Cygwin shell, and Wireshark in another to monitor RawCap's output:

**Shell 1:**

```
RawCap.exe -f 127.0.0.1 dumpfile.pcap
```

**Shell 2:**

```
# How do I tell Wireshark to show only traffic to port 10000?
tail -c +0 -f dumpfile.pcap | Wireshark.exe -k -i -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate flag for instructing wireshark to filter the displayed packets is `-Y`, as its man page reports:

> `-Y <display filter>`      start with the given display filter

For filtering the destination port of TCP, use `tcp.dstport==X` where `X` specifies the port.

Therefore, the full command is:

```
tail -c +0 -f dumpfile.pcap | wireshark -k -i - -Y "tcp.dstport==10000"
```

---

[This](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters) is a good starting point for information on display filters. A full reference on the subject is available [here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/) and a detailed explanation of its syntax is available [here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html). However, it's worth noting that most basic filters can be found via a simple online search.